# Calculate counts and averages by group for various columns in a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, count, average, summarize

I am trying to summarize a dataset.

I am looking to produce a table with counts and averages all in one.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    "Species" = c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D"), 
    "Location" =  c("A","B","C","B","A","D","D","E"), 
    "Sample size" = c(1,30,6,2,5,10,3,300), 
    "Frequency"=c(0,0.3,80,0.5,0.01,0.6,1,2)
  )

df
```

Data produces a table like this:

```
     Species Country Sample.size Frequency
1       A       A           1         0
2       B       B          30       0.3
3       C       C           6        80
4       D       B           2       0.5
5       A       A           5      0.01
6       B       D          10       0.6
7       C       D           3         1
8       D       E         300         2
```

I am trying to make a table with a column for: species, a **count** for the number of times a species occurs, a **count** for the number of countries a species occurs in, an **average** for sample size per species, and an **average** frequency per species.

Essentially, I am trying to get a table like this:

```
Species species_count #_of_Countries Avg_Sample.size Avg_Frequency
A       2             2              10              0
B       2             3              3               0.01
C       3             4              1               20
D       5             1              5               0.5
```

I am relatively new to R, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the expected output based on the input example as I couldn't get the count correctly

Comment: No its not the expected output based on the sample, I just put random numbers in. But it's the general format

Comment: To get the mean, the 'Sample.size', 'Frequency' should be numeric

Comment: Oh right, sorry! I edited the example to be numeric.

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(Avg_Sample_size = mean(Sample.size), Avg_Frequency = mean(Frequency), species_count = n()) %>% group_by(Location) %>% mutate(NumberOfCountries = n()) %>% distinct`. As the expected is not correct, I couldn't crosscheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want
    library(dplyr)

```
Summary_df <- df %>% 
group_by(species) %>%
summarize(species_count = n(), 
                 country_count = sum(!is.na(Country)), 
             Avg_sample_size = mean(Sample.size), 
             Avg_frequency = mean(Frequency))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked (sort of). The table produced data for species count, avg sample size and avg frequency, but the country count did not work. It gave the same results as species count, instead of counting countries